# Apache rewrite addresses bar too, while RewriteUrl works correctyl

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

in .htaccess file I have this rule

```
RewriteRule ^about/*$ http://example.com/about.php [L]
```

While the redirect is succesfully, in the address bar is shown the real path:

http://example.com/about.php

instead

http://example.com/about/

I can't find the problem. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Remove the host name from the target path if you want to Rewrite /about to /about.php

```
RewriteRule ^about/*$ /about.php [L]
```

Comment: I have the same problem.

Comment: what url are you going to?

Comment: Could be a problem in Apache configuration file?